# how to avoid a request with 304 status code returned in chrome?

Tags: html, http, meta-tags, cache-control

I have a html page,and add some meta tags like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" Content="public" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" Content="Mon, 08 Jun 2013 03:37:26 GMT" />
```

My server is tomcat, after this HTML page is cached in client browsers, I shut down my tomcat.

And then I tried to access this HTML page in different browsers.

IE can access this page successfully, but Chrome failed.

And then I restarted my tomcat, and made a test in Chrome and IE.

I found that chrome still sent a request with a 304 code returned, but IE did not send this request.

So how to avoid this request in Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I do n't think this is an error. The [3xx](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3) denotes a redirection. The real errors are 4xx (client error) and [5xx](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.5) (server error).

If a client gets a [304 Not Modified](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.5), then it's the client's responsibility to display the resouce in question from its own cache. In general, the proxy shouldn't worry about this. It's just the messenger.

```
catch (WebException ex)
{


    if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
    {
        int statusCode = (int) ((HttpWebResponse) ex.Response).StatusCode;
        listenerContext.Response.StatusCode = statusCode;
        listenerContext.Response.StatusDescription = ex.Message;
        log("WARNING", uri, "WebException/ProtocolError: " + ex.GetType() + " - " + ex.Message);
    }
    else
    {
        log("ERROR", uri, "WebException - " + ex.GetType() + " - " + ex.Message);

    }

    listenerContext.Response.Close();
}
```

Comment: i am looking for a solution in client.i just want browser cache the pure html page forever ,and never request it from server,no matter server is running or shut down.

Comment: You may want to look into something like http://www.w3.org/TR/offline-webapps/ in that case?